# Why does bandpass performance break down at low frequencies?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, continuous-signals, bandpass

I've got a basic bandpass filter design that works great at higher frequencies, but breaks down at around 150 Hz. Here's the MATLAB code:

```
[b,a] = butter(4, [106 212]./(Fs/2));
output = filter(b,a,signal);
```

I also notice that decreasing the filter order lowers this "breakdown" frequency. [This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41891/bandpass-filters-with-python-for-low-frequencies) asks a similar question and the answer does fix the problem, but I'm not sure I understand *why*.

Here are the filter coefficients for the given example (where it starts to break down):

```
B = 2.12e-09, 0.00e+00, -8.49e-09, 0.00e+00, 1.27e-08, 0.00e+00, -8.49e-09, 0.00e+00, 2.12e-09
A = 1.00e+00, -7.96e+00, 2.77e+01, -5.51e+01, 6.86e+01, -5.46e+01, 2.72e+01, -7.73e+00, 9.61e-01
```

…and here are coefficients for a slightly higher frequency (mid-band of 250 Hz), where it doesn't:

```
B = 2.45e-08, 0.00e+00, -9.82e-08, 0.00e+00, 1.47e-07, 0.00e+00, -9.82e-08, 0.00e+00, 2.45e-08
A = 1.00e+00, -7.93e+00, 2.75e+01, -5.46e+01, 6.76e+01, -5.37e+01, 2.66e+01, -7.55e+00, 9.36e-01
```

Comment: What's your sampling frequency?

Comment: I really think that hotpaw's answer in the question you linked answers this.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the comment. Sampling rate is 44100 Hz.

Comment: 1 - use fdatool, freqz, fvtool to view the frequency response

2 - try increasing the order of the IIR, you will be able to get closer to a "brickwall" frequency response

3 - Alternative, Keep the same filter order, but increase your margins. Use 80 Hz as f1 and 300 Hz as f2 for example.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for this, though I'm not looking to solve the "breakdown" (did this by other means). Just want to understand what exactly in the filtering process causes the issue.

Comment: As answered already, it's an ill conditioned sequence of arithmetic operations, similar to getting closer and closer to trying to divide by zero, resulting in either nonsense or numerical noise.

Comment: Well you should try to understand the effect of the transition width  and the order of the IIR filter.

Hint : Higher-order = steeper transition from stopband to passband.