# Third octave bandpass filter with python

Tags: filters, python, bandpass, scipy

I am very new to signal processing and coding which is why my questions might be really basic. I have a signal of the acoustic pressure p'(t) and I would like to use a third octave bandpass filter in Python.
I came across these two approaches to filtering with scipy:

[Bandpass filters with python for low frequencies](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41891/bandpass-filters-with-python-for-low-frequencies)
https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ButterworthBandpass.html

At the moment I am able to use one bandpass filter with the following code for a simple example (mostly taken from link 2):

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter
from scipy.signal import freqz

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
   nyq = 0.5 * fs
   low = lowcut / nyq
   high = highcut / nyq
   b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
   return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
   b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
   y = lfilter(b, a, data)
   return y

t = np.linspace(0,1,1000)    
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*100*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*10*t)

T = t[1] - t[0]
fs = 1/T
print(fs)
y = butter_bandpass_filter(s, 90,110,fs,order=5)


plt.figure(1)    
plt.plot(t,s,'b',t,y,'r')    

plt.figure(2)
N = s.size
f = np.linspace(0, 1/T, N)
s -= np.mean(s)
fft = np.fft.fft(s)
plt.bar(f[:N // 2], np.abs(fft)[:N // 2] * 1 / N, width=5)

plt.figure(3)
N = y.size
f = np.linspace(0, 1/T, N)
y -= np.mean(y)
fft = np.fft.fft(y)
plt.bar(f[:N // 2], np.abs(fft)[:N // 2] * 1 / N, width=5)

plt.show()
```

The dft shows the results I expected. So my first question would be whether this procedure for a single filter is reasonable?

My second question: How could I use this code to build a third octave bandpass filter with the following center frequencies (for example):

```
f_one_third = [10,12.5,16,20,25,31.5,40,50,63,80,100,125,160,200,250,315,400,500,630,800,1000,1250,1600,2000,2500,3150,4000,5000,6300,8000,10000,12500,16000,20000]
```

Simply using one filter after the other seems to be very inefficient and I guess that there is a much more efficient.
The first link gives an approach for a third octave filter, but I am honestly not sure how to "use". I am basically missing the equivalent of the def butter_bandpass_filter function from the code above.

I would appreciate any help immensely!

Comment: you should generally use `sosfilt`, not `lfilter`.  we even added this in the docstring :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed a function to easily perform octave and fractional octave filtering, it is available on github: [PyOctaveBand](https://github.com/jmrplens/PyOctaveBand)

It uses the SOS coefficients and performs downsampling to filter correctly at low frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

> The dft shows the results I expected. So my first question would be
>   whether this procedure for a single filter is reasonable?

Sort of. For very low frequencies and/or high orders, using transfer function representation (b,a) runs into numerical problems. Use second order section representation and sosfilt() instead.

> My second question: How could I use this code to build a third octave
>   bandpass filter with the following center frequencies (for example):

Depends a bit on what you are planning to do with the resulting signals. Just doing lots of parallel filters is not an unreasonable approach. The alternative would be a frequency domain method, but this is unlikely to be cheaper if you need all results in the time domain. However, if you just want to build a 3rd octave spectrum analyzer, you just need the time averaged band energy as the function of time, which can be done in the frequency domain pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks! Alright, I will use sosfilt() then. My desired final ouput is a frequency spectrum in which the amplitudes are assigned to the third octave center frequencies, I think that this is a 3rd octave spectrum analyzer. Does that mean that I don't even need a bandpass filter like the one in the code above?